# Why does my Mac M1 have different shells for administrator and ci?

Tags: macos, shell

I'm ssh-ing to my mac runner, when I log in as administrator the `echo $SHELL` gives `/bin/zsh` but when I do the same thing on another user it's `/bin/bash` why and how can I sync the shells to the same type?

I used `chsh -s /bin/zsh` on the other user but when I `echo $SHELL` again it's still `/bin/bash`

Edit: I'm using WSL2 with bash as default shell

Comment: This is a better question for [apple.se] or [unix.se] than Stack Overflow; we're only for questions about _writing software_.

Comment: (And each invocation of `chsh` is specific to an individual account -- by default the current one, though if you're root you can tell it to change a different user's shell; it's not a global / system-wide setting).

Comment: `SHELL` doesn't change its value immediately in an existing shell session.

Comment: (And there's a lot of customization one can do to change the login process, including causing the user account's shell preference to be ignored)

Comment: macOS is not the only OS that uses a different (not-necessarily POSIX) shell as a default login shell. Ubuntu, for example, uses `dash` as its system shell and `bash` as the login shell.

Comment: Anyhow -- when you ask this somewhere it's on-topic, it would be helpful to include more details. If you're logging out and back in between when you run `chsh` and check the current shell, _show that in the question_ via a transcript of the session so people don't need to make assumptions about your process.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks! Logged out and in solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CharlesDuffy answered: Logout and login again to see changes